# Unable to edit/add user in Joomla 2.5.16 - error message is missing

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-community-builder

I am unable to edit or add a user in Joomla 2.5.16 and Community Builder 1.9.1.

When I try to save a profile I receive a message : "Save failed with the following error:". But there is nothing after that message (no error message, no code). Of course the changes aren't saved.

In Joomla and Apache logs there is nothing too.

I encounter that problem in joomla's user management and in CB.

Do you have any idea on how to correct that problem or at least to find more information about what is broken ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that problem by upgrading to Joomla 2.5.18.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug registration process in `function register()` in file `yoursite\components\com_users\models\registration.php` for front end of your site. 
Debug registration data of your site.